# MongoDB do not return document if condition in lookup fails

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, document

I am having this mongo DB query which queries a collection called `songs` and for each song, returns the respective album associated:

```
db.songs.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
            from: "albums",
            let: { album: '$album' },
            as: "album",
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ['$albumId', '$$album._id'] },
                            { $eq: ['$status', 'Draft'] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
}])
```

In the above query, my intention was to return a song only if the album was in `Draft` status, but in contrast, it returns all songs, and for the ones for which the album is not in Draft, it just returns an empty array inside the lookup. How can I not return the song document at all if the album is not in Draft?

Additionally, is it possible to flatten the results in the document? ie, merge all the fields of albums into the song document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you perform the `$lookup` you can filter out the documents with an empty array:

```
{ $match: { album: { $ne: [] } }}
```

Then there is [an example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#-mergeobjects) in the MongoDB documentation for the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects) operator that is very similar to your case. Assuming that each song belongs to one album, put together your aggregation pipeline may look like this:

```
db.songs.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
            from: "albums",
            let: { album: '$album' },
            as: "album",
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ['$albumId', '$$album._id'] },
                            { $eq: ['$status', 'Draft'] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
},
{   $match: { album: { $ne: [] } }},
{
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$album", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
},
{ $project: { album: 0 } }
])
```

Comment: The solution works well, but in my case, the album has a title field and song also has this field, in such a case, only one of the values is shown. There are several common fields which are getting overwritten

Answer (score 1):

You may want to experiment going in the other direction:  find albums in `status = Draft` then get the songs:

```js
db.album.aggregate([
    {$match: {"status":"Draft"}}
    ,{$lookup: {from: "song",
        localField: "album", foreignField: "album",
                as: "songs"}}
    // songs is now an array of docs.  Run $map to turn that into an
    // array of just the song title, and overwrite it (think  x = x + 1):
    ,{$addFields: {songs: {$map: {
                            input: "$songs",
                            in: "$$this.song"
    }} }}
]);
```

If you have a LOT of material in the `song` document, you can use the fancier `$lookup` to cut down the size of the docs in the lookup array -- but you still need the `$map` to turn it into an array of strings.

```js
db.album.aggregate([
    {$match: {"status":"Draft"}}
    ,{$lookup: {from: "song",
                let: { aid: "$album" },
                pipeline: [
                    {$match: {$expr: {$eq:["$album","$$aid"]}}},
                    {$project: {song:true}}
                ],
                as: "songs"}}

    ,{$addFields: {songs: {$map: {
                            input: "$songs",
                            in: "$$this.song"
    }} }}

]);
```